# Why didn‘t child subscriber's onComplete() method invoke when use retryWhen() in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

according to the [retryWhen()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#retryWhen%28rx.functions.Func1%29) doc:

> Returns an Observable that emits the same values as the source
>   observable with the exception of an onError. An onError notification
>   from the source will result in the emission of a Throwable item to the
>   Observable provided as an argument to the notificationHandler
>   function. If that Observable calls onComplete or onError then retry
>   will call onCompleted or onError on the child subscription. Otherwise,
>   this Observable will resubscribe to the source Observable.

when the count1 value reached 3,subscriber.onCompleted() will be invoked;In my option,child subscriber's onComplete() method will be invoked after subscriber.onCompleted() is invoked and "child_onCompleted" will show up in the output,but it isn`t;Why is that happen?

```
  count1 = 0;  

      Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                System.out.println("call_onErr ");
                subscriber.onError(new Throwable("gg!"));
            }
        }).retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {

                System.out.println("fun_call+" + observable);
                return observable.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {

                        if (count1 < 3) {
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                                    System.out.println("fun_call_onNext " + "  count=" + count1);
                                    subscriber.onNext(1000);
                                }
                            });
                        } else
                            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                                    System.out.println("fun_call_onCompleted " + "   " + count1);
                                    subscriber.onCompleted();//this is the subscriber!!!!!!!
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });


            }
        }).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("child_onCompleted ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("child_err ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                System.out.println("child_onNext " + integer + " ");
            }
        });
```

the output is:

```
System.out﹕ fun_call+rx.Observable@3ecb7134
System.out﹕ call_onErr
System.out﹕ fun_call_onNext   count=1
System.out﹕ call_onErr
System.out﹕ fun_call_onNext   count=2
System.out﹕ call_onErr
System.out﹕ fun_call_onNext   count=3
System.out﹕ call_onErr
System.out﹕ fun_call_onCompleted    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have flatMap which won't complete if you send it an empty Observable. Instead, you can use special values inside it and communicate with a `takeWhile` operator to trigger completion:

```
Observable.error(new Throwable("gg!"))
.retryWhen(o -> {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    return o.flatMap(e -> {
        if (counter.getAndIncrement() < 3) {
            return Observable.just(0);
        }
        return Observable.just(1);
    })
    .takeWhile(v -> v == 0);
})
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.